# Sabre flight search - BFM. get multiple Fare Type for ticket?

Tags: sabre

I am looking for search multiple Fare Type for per ticket ? i wan't get Fare Type ex: Economy, Economy Flex, example :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWJaI.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Branded Fares is the feature in question; once is enabled, the response will include that information as well as the image you submitted.